# Firefox, не работает DOM дерево javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Не могу получить содержимое тегов с html! Хочу вывести в консоль.
Вот структура html:

```
 <div class="text">
 <p>Первый абзац</p>
 <p>Второй абзац</p>
 </div>
```

Вот скрипт:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".text p");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
console.log(elems[i].innerText);
 }
```

Если я просто попытаюсь вывести обьект
console.log(elems);
то выводит NodeList [] и при етом length: 0; Почему? Должно же быть 2! Если я пытаюсь принудительно брать элемент через индексы(elems[0]), то выводит: undefined
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

Comment: скрипт вызывается ДО того, как элементы добавились в DOM

Comment: Спасибо большое!